# Making pre-packed .db file for pre-populating a Room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Given a situation that a .db file was needed to pre-populate a Room database with a problem arising at the run-time saying `Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema`. Among many columns only two are not matching that are both defined as `Boolean` type in Kotlin.

Kotlin entity class:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "xxx")
var xxx: Boolean = false ,

@ColumnInfo(name = "yyy")
var yyy: Boolean? = null
```

Error message:

```
Expected:
    TableInfo{name='zzz', columns={xxx=Column{name='xxx', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, yyy=Column{name='yyy', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
    TableInfo{name='zzz', columns={xxx=Column{name='xxx', type='NUMERIC', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, yyy=Column{name='yyy', type='NUMERIC', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

For creation of pre-packed .db file `DB Browser for SQLite` is being used and this is what comes as query for creating the actual zzz table:

```
CREATE TABLE "zzz" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    ...
    "xxx"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "yyy"   INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Even though xxx and yyy columns are defined to be of INTEGER type they end up being of NUMERIC type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-packagaed database being opened read and inspected has a schema where the column types for xxx and yyy are not INTEGER but are NUMERIC (or considered to be NUMERIC).

Room does not handle a type of NUMERIC as basically it is the catchall type and therefore it cannot definitively determine the type that should be used for the member variable, it could only guess. The message is therefore saying that it considers the pre-packaged database as unsuitable in it's incarnation.

You need to either recreate the pre-packaged database using a schema that sets the xxx and zzz columns to be INTEGER e.g. using :-

```
CREATE TABLE "zzz" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    ...
    "xxx"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "yyy"   INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
```

or you need to ALTER the zzz table in pre-packaged database so that the schema is as above. In short Room will not handle a column that has been defined that has a derived type of NUMERIC as it doesn't know how to handle such a type as NUMERIC as a type is a catchall.

To ALTER the table you could use something along the lines of :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zzz_amended;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "zzz_amended" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    /* ... */
    "xxx"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "yyy"   INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO zzz_amended SELECT * FROM zzz;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zzz_old;
ALTER TABLE zzz RENAME TO zzz_old;
ALTER TABLE zzz_amended RENAME TO zzz;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zzz_old;
```

A simpler Alternative could be to use the **RoomDatabaseBuilder**'s **createFromAsset** or **createFromFile** method, but this might then need changes to the enitity to suit what the methods determine the schema to be.

---

## Additional Re Comment :-

> Well the schema used for the table zzz is as shown where xxx and yyy
>   are of type INTEGER. And createFromAsset() method is being used. But
>   for some reason outcome of createFromAsset() is that xxx and yyy are
>   of type NUMERIC instead of type INTEGER as defined when creating the
>   zzz table.

## 1.

Consider the following Database with the table created as you say it has been created. e.g.

[image]

Populated with as per :-

[image]

The database being available at [so59224033.db](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eDQy8Ws-ArzXLMNB6AWAtiF0m4BYnR8q)

## 2

Also consider the following Simple App :-

**Zzz**

```
@Entity(tableName = "zzz")
 data class Zzz (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "xxx")
    var xxx: Boolean = false ,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "yyy")
    var yyy: Boolean? = null
)
```

**ZzzDao**

```
@Dao
interface ZzzDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM zzz")
    fun getAllFromzzz() :List<Zzz>
}
```

**AppDatabase**

```
@Database(version = 1,entities = [Zzz::class])
abstract class AppDatabase :RoomDatabase() { 
    abstract fun getZzzDao() :ZzzDao
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val appDatabase :AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this,AppDatabase::class.java,"mydb")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .createFromAsset("so59224033.db")
            .build()

        val listofZzz = appDatabase.getZzzDao().getAllFromzzz()
        for (z  in listofZzz) {
            Log.d("ZzzINFO","ID = " + z.id + " xxx = " + z.xxx + " yyy = " + z.yyy)
        }
    }
}
```

## 3

The result not being any conflict (thus eliminating a bug with Room, at least if using the latest Room libraries, with the available code) :-

```
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2'
```

Rather the result is as expected :-

```
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 1 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 2 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 3 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 4 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 5 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 6 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 7 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 8 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 9 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 10 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 11 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 12 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 13 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 14 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 15 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 16 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.196 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 17 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.197 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 18 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.197 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 19 xxx = false yyy = null
2019-12-08 08:55:23.197 19370-19370/? D/ZzzINFO: ID = 20 xxx = false yyy = null
```

## 4

If the source database is changed e.g. to use :-

[image]

Then the result is :-

```
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='zzz', columns={yyy=Column{name='yyy', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, xxx=Column{name='xxx', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='zzz', columns={yyy=Column{name='yyy', type='NUMERIC', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='NULL'}, xxx=Column{name='xxx', type='typethatwillbe_N_U_M_E_R_I_C', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

i.e. Your issue has been replicated by using a database in the assets folder that does not conform to the expectations.

i.e. the cause is that the database in the assets folder is incorrect.

I would suggest deleting the file from the assets folder, double checking that the columns are defined as INTEGER and then copying the file into the assets folder.

Comment: Thank you Mike for replying. Well the schema used for the table `zzz` is as shown where `xxx` and `yyy` are of type `INTEGER`. And `createFromAsset()` method is being used. But for some reason outcome of `createFromAsset()` is that `xxx` and `yyy` are of type `NUMERIC` instead of type `INTEGER` as defined when creating the `zzz` table. The question was, why does this happen, how to solve it or is there some other preferable kind of tool one should use for creating pre-packed .db file other than `DB Browser for SQLite` that I've used.

Comment: @J.Grbo Either there's a bug in **createFromAsset** (see amended answer) or the pre-packaged database does not have the schema that you believe that it has. I would hazard my bets on the latter. The answer has been updated with a demonstration showing that the schema given produces the correct results.

Comment: @J.Grbo as has now been shown in the yet further amended asnwer, that the schema in the per-populated database in the asset folder is the issue.

Comment: I've already moved away from createFromAsset to providing a callback when the database is being creating for pre-populating it, since I already spend quite a lot time on this one without any success. As I replied to your unedited  answer I've told myself I am gonna give it a last try, but delayed it to later since I was doing something else, but as I saw you took your time to test it, I've re-implemented it again, and it works.

Comment: Don't know what was going on today, I was not double checking but 8x checking that SQL query for table creating is as I've posted here. But nonetheless problem is solved. Thank you big time Mike for taking your time on this one.